# a particularly important variable in my program will not change

Tags: python

The below code is for a pretty simple enemy encounter concept.

```
# ENEMY ENCOUNTER CONCEPT

import random

PLAYERNAME = 'PLAYER'
ENEMYNAME = 'DEMON'
playerHP = 100
enemyHP = 100
print('You encounter %s!' % (ENEMYNAME))
playerMove = 0
playerAttackDamage = 0
playerDefending = 0
enemyAttackNumber = 0
enemyAttackDamage = 0
enemyDefending = 0
playerFrozen = 0

def drawEnemy():
    print('''[this isn't important now.]''')

def firstAttack(): #randomly decides which entity will attack first.
    if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
        return 'PLAYER'
    else:
        return 'ENEMY'

def playerAttack(playerMove, playerAttackDamage, ENEMYNAME, playerDefending, playerHP): #asks the player what he/she wants to do. performs given action.
    playerMove = 0
    playerDefending = 0
    while playerMove not in range(1,3):
        print('''What will you do?
1. Attack
2. Defend''')
        playerMove = input()
        playerMove = int(playerMove)
        if int(playerMove) == 1:
                playerAttackDamage = random.randint(5, 10)
                print('You attack %s. %s receives %s damage.' % (ENEMYNAME, ENEMYNAME, playerAttackDamage))
        if int(playerMove) == 2:
                playerDefending = 1
                print('You are defending. As long as you are defending, %s\'s attacks will be halved in damage.' % (ENEMYNAME))
    return playerAttackDamage
    return playerDefending


def enemyAttack(enemyAttackNumber, enemyAttackDamage, playerFrozen, PLAYERNAME, ENEMYNAME, enemyDefending): #the enemy attacks.
    enemyDefending = 0
    enemyAttackNumber = random.randint(0, 18)
    if enemyAttackNumber in range(0, 8):
                enemyAttackDamage = random.randint(6, 12)
                print('%s attacks %s. %s receives %s damage.' % (ENEMYNAME, PLAYERNAME, PLAYERNAME, enemyAttackDamage))
    if enemyAttackNumber in range(8, 12):
                enemyAttackDamage = random.randint(10, 20)
                print('%s summons fire! %s receives %s damage.' % (ENEMYNAME, PLAYERNAME, enemyAttackDamage))
    if enemyAttackNumber in range(12, 18):
                enemyDefending = 1
                print('%s is defending. Your attacks will only deal half damage as long as it is defending.' % (ENEMYNAME))
    if enemyAttackNumber == 18:
                enemyAttackDamage = random.randint(10, 20)
                playerFrozen = 1
                print('%s summons ice! %s receives %s damage and is now frozen.' % (ENEMYNAME, PLAYERNAME, enemyAttackDamage))
    return enemyAttackDamage
    return enemyDefending

def playerDamage(playerHP, enemyAttackDamage, playerDefending):
    if playerDefending == 0:
        playerHP -= enemyAttackDamage
    else:
        playerHP -= (enemyAttackDamage/2)
    return playerHP

def enemyDamage(enemyHP, playerAttackDamage, enemyDefending):
    if enemyDefending == 0:
        enemyHP -= playerAttackDamage
    else:
        enemyHP -= (playerAttackDamage/2)
    return enemyHP

def playerIsDead(playerHP):
    return playerHP < 1

def enemyIsDead(enemyHP):
    return enemyHP < 1

def playAgain():
    print('Would you like to play again?')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

while True:
    drawEnemy()
    turn = firstAttack()
    fighting = True

    while fighting:
        playerHP = playerDamage(playerHP, enemyAttackDamage, playerDefending)
        enemyHP = enemyDamage(enemyHP, playerAttackDamage, enemyDefending)
        if turn == 'PLAYER' and playerFrozen == 0:
            print('Player HP: %s' % (playerHP))
            print('Enemy HP: %s' % (enemyHP))
            playerAttack(playerMove, playerAttackDamage, ENEMYNAME, playerDefending, playerHP)
            if enemyIsDead(enemyHP):
                ('%s has been slain! You win!' % (ENEMYNAME))
                fighting = False

            else:
                turn = 'COMPUTER'
                playerFrozen = 0
        else:
            enemyAttack(enemyAttackNumber, enemyAttackDamage, playerFrozen, PLAYERNAME, ENEMYNAME, enemyDefending)
            if playerIsDead(playerHP):
                ('%s has defeated you! Game over!' % (ENEMYNAME))
                fighting = False
            else:
                turn = 'PLAYER'

    if not playAgain():
        break
```

My problem? The HP won't change, so the game can't actually be finished. I've tried to rewrite the HP code and place it in other parts of the program, but none of these attempts have worked. What in particular is causing this?

My version of Python is 3.6.4, in case that information is needed.

Comment: in enemyAttack () function I noticed there are two returns<br>    returns enemyAttackDamage<br>
    return enemyDefending<br>maybe that's why, because the second return never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `playerAttack` and `enemyAttack` functions return the updated values of `playerAttackDamage` and `enemyAttackDamage`, respectively, but the callers don't have any variables to receive the returning values.

Also, those two functions try to return `playerDefending` and `enemyDefending` after it already returns another value. They should return the two updated values as tuples, so in `playerAttack`, it should:

```
return playerAttackDamage, playerDefending
```

and in 'enemyAttack`, it should:

```
return enemyAttackDamage, enemyDefending
```

Then change those caller lines to:

```
playerAttackDamage, playerDefending = playerAttack(playerMove, playerAttackDamage, ENEMYNAME, playerDefending, playerHP)
```

and

```
enemyAttackDamage, enemyDefending = enemyAttack(enemyAttackNumber, enemyAttackDamage, playerFrozen, PLAYERNAME, ENEMYNAME, enemyDefending)
```

Comment: actually, for the return functions that you suggested, i'm getting another error for trying to convert a tuple to an integer when trying to subtract HP. i've tried using a list as well, and that didn't appear to work either.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[directory]\unfinished encounter.py", line 134, in <module>
    playerHP = playerDamage(playerHP, enemyAttackDamage, playerDefending)
  File "[directory]\unfinished encounter.py", line 88, in playerDamage
    playerHP -= int(enemyAttackDamage)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: @Noah Like I suggested in my answer, the caller needs to assign the returning value of `playerAttack` to a tuple `playerAttaackDamage, playerDefending` instead of just `playerAttackDamage`.

Answer (score 0):

The `enemyAttackDamage` and `enemyAttackNumber` are 0. Doesn't that mean that they don't affect the `playerHP`?
I tried to change those and it did change the playerHP.
Also, in the `playerAttack` function, you are trying to use 2 returns and the program won't ever get to the second return since it exits from the first one.

Comment: i set those variables to 0 at the beginning with the intention of them being changed later in the game. I tried changing the initial variable value, and while it does end up changing the HP, it doesn't change it by the right amount; only by the initial value itself.

and for the double return, is it possible to return two values at once?